# Indexing FTP document with solrj

Tags: solr, solrj

I want to index some documents with solrj API's but the URL of these documents is FTP.

How to set username and password for FTP acount in solrj?

Answer (score 0):

UpdateRequest - stream.url does not support authentication
We had to add a custom patch to add authentication to it @ https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2240

Suggestions -
 1. Expose the content through http without authentication and use stream.url
 2. Read the file from ftp with auth in java and use the stream.body to pass the content as stream.

Comment: Would you mind give me some sample code or useful link to use stram.url or stream.body in solrj